# Having difficultly outputting 2D array

Tags: ruby, class, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a problem where I need to create a `CartesianProduct` class.  I should be able to pass this class 2 lists, and then output the Cartesian product (all possible combinations) of these lists.

So far I can create an object out of this class, create all possible combinations, but when I try to output these results to screen I get each item on its own row as if it doesnt realize it is an array.

My code:

```
class CartesianProduct
    include Enumerable
    # Your code here
    def initialize(a,b)
        @output = []
        a.each do |x|
            b.each do |y|
                if !(output.include? [x,y])
                    output << [x,y]
                end
            end
        end
    end

    #getter
    def output
        @output
    end

    def each
        @output.each do |a| puts a end
    end

    #setter
    def output=(a,b)
        a.each do |x|
            b.each do |y|
                if !(output.include? [a,b])
                    output << [a,b]
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

What Im using to test:

```
c = CartesianProduct.new([:a,:b], [4,5])
=> #<CartesianProduct:0x93569f8 @output=[[:a, 4], [:a, 5], [:b, 4], [:b, 5]]>
```

Testing is done via the following command: `c.each { |elt| puts elt.inspect }`

I get:

```
irb(main):1403:0> c.each { |elt| puts elt.inspect }
a
4
a
5
b
4
b
5
=> [[:a, 4], [:a, 5], [:b, 4], [:b, 5]]
```

but I should be getting:

```
# [:a, 4]
# [:a, 5]
# [:b, 4]
# [:b, 5]
```

My output is not printing the `symbols` as symbols but rather converting to string, and its print each item on its own line...

This is homework, so I'm not looking for an answer, but a nudge in the right direction would help quite a bit.

**EDIT**   ========================================================================
Changing my definition of `each` in the class resolved this issue.

```
def each
    @output.map do |x|
        yield x
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my definition of each in the class resolved this issue.

```
def each
    @output.map do |x|
        yield x
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are applying `each` on `c`, which is an instance of `CartesianProduct`. You need to do `each` on the `@output` of it. As for how to access `@output` from outside, you should know; it is a basic thing.

Comment: Even though I defined `each` inside my class?  I thought when I did this and then called `c.each` it would use my method which references `@output`?

Comment: Okay, now I see what you are doing. Either 1) Take out your definition of `each`, and call `@output` when you do `each`. That definition is very strange. Or, 2) if you insist in defining `each`, then you have to use `inspect` there, and when you call `each`, all you need is `c.each` and nothing more.

Comment: Im sure it's very bizarre, very new Ruby user. :)  When I take out my each and run the test, I get everything one 1 line. `=> [[:a, 4], [:a, 5], [:b, 4], [:b, 5]]`

Comment: I wrote that you should run `each` on the `@output`, not `c`.

Comment: That is what I did, I changed my `def each @output.each end` and the output I get is now: `=> #<Enumerator: [[:a, 4], [:a, 5], [:b, 4], [:b, 5]]:each>`  Am I miss understanding your recommendation?  Are you saying to perform `each` on `@putput` from outside the class?  I need to run the test provided so Im not sure if I can do that. Hrm.

Comment: I think I got it.  if I do `@output.map do |x| p x end` it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting with Ruby, but I think I found the cause:
When you call `c.each { |elt| puts elt.inspect }`
it first executes the call you have defined in the class. The result of that are strings that are passed to the block in the test `{ |elt| puts elt.inspect }` which splits them on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of #each in `CartesianProduct` does not accept a block, so, for an instance `c`, passing a block to `c.each` has no effect. Try this:

```
c.each { |elt| raise "an error!" }

# no error is raised because the block is not called.
```

Now, your definition of `each` calls `puts` on each of the arrays in `@output`. Calling `puts` on an array will iterate over each element, even within nested arrays (in other words, the flattened version of the array):

```
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :006 > puts [1,2,[3,4]]
1
2
3
4
=> nil
```

I believe what you want is an implementation of `each` that passes a given block to the each method of `@output`:

```
def each(&block)
  @output.each(&block)
end
```